# JQuery submit never submits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hey guys I'm trying to work my way through this but am having an issue even getting inside my function for form submit in JQuery, I've set up several console.logs but it never actually
gets inside my first functio, does anyone know what I did wrong?

Code

```
 <script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
 <script> google.load('jquery', '1.7.1'); </script>

 <script>
    console.log('outside function');
    $("form").submit(function() {
        console.log('submit happened');
        queryJsonServer($(this), "class/");
        return false;
    });

    function queryJsonServer(form, path) {
        var inputs = $('input:radio').serializeArray();
        var params = createAction("saveFormData", inputs);
        var url = path + "json.php";
        $.post(url, params, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.("form").submit();
        });

    }
 </script>
```

HTML

```
<form>

<fieldset>
<legend>Select Orders</legend>

<table id='master'></table>

  </div> <!-- end input1 -->
    <div>
     <button name="select" type="submit" id="btnLoad" value="load">Refresh</button>
     <button name="select" type="submit" id="btnJson" value="down">Download JSON</button>
     <button name="select" type="submit" id="btnView" value="view">View/Enter</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to wrap your function in the jQuery function so that it executes when DOM is ready.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    console.log('outside function');
    $("form").submit(function() {
        console.log('submit happened');
        queryJsonServer($(this), "class/");
        return false;
    });

    function queryJsonServer(form, path) {
        var inputs = $('input:radio').serializeArray();
        var params = createAction("saveFormData", inputs);
        var url = path + "json.php";
        $.post(url, params, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.("form").submit();
        });

    }
});
 </script>
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks greatly. Waiting to approve ;)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
```

…binds a submit event to every form *in the DOM* **at the time the script runs**.

Since the script:

- Appears in the `<head>`
- Isn't delayed by being called onready / onload / etc

… there are no form elements when the event handler is bound.

Either move the script so it appears after the form element (e.g. just before `</body>`), or call the function in your ready event handler.